# C++ Issue with scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, undefined-behavior, storage-duration

I am trying to swap a pointer to point to the address of a new class instance created inside a method, but once back to main, the reference is lost, is this because of scope? Could someone please care to explain? Does c/c++ have reference counting?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    int myNum;
    std::string myString;
    MyClass(int my_num, std::string my_string)
    {
        myNum = my_num;
        myString = my_string;
    }
};

void SwapRef(MyClass **p)
{    
    MyClass b(99, "test");
    *p = &b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass a(1, "main");

    MyClass* aPtr = (MyClass*)0;
    aPtr = &a;

    std::cout << "myNum is: " << aPtr->myNum << " myString is: " << aPtr->myString << "\n";

    SwapRef(&aPtr);

    std::cout << "myNum is: " << aPtr->myNum << " myString is: " << aPtr->myString << "\n";

#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
    system("pause");
#endif
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

myNum is: 1 myString is: main

myNum is: -858993460 myString is:

Comment: When a function ends, all non-static variables declared inside it are destroyed

Comment: `*p = &b;` - this will cause `*p` to be a dangling pointer once the function returns and `b` destroyed.

Comment: If you want reference counting use `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
void SwapRef(MyClass **p)
{    
    MyClass b(99, "test");
    *p = &b;
}
```

is wrong. The object `b` having automatic storage duration will not be alive after exiting the function. So the pointer `aPtr` assigned in the function with the address of the local object using the expression statement

```
*p = &b;
```

will be invalid after exiting the function.

Dereferencing such a pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you could write

```
**p = b;
```

using the generated by the compiler the default copy assignment operator.

The function could be correct if the object declared within the function would have static storage duration like

```
void SwapRef(MyClass **p)
{    
    static MyClass b(99, "test");
    *p = &b;
}
```

In this case it will be alive after exiting the function.

Pay attention to that you should include header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

because it is not necessary that the header `<iostream>` includes the header `<string>`.